# Declaring normal distribution generator in .h file

Tags: c++, random

I have a member function that I want to generate a lot of Gaussian distributed random numbers, but I don't want to initialize the random number generator on every call to that function, thinking it would be slower. I was thinking I could declare the random number generator in the .h file and initialize it in the constructor, but I am unsure of the syntax to do this, or even if it will work. Also, I am not sure if this is indeed necessary to save computation time.

In other words, I would like to create a std::normal_distribution generator in the .h file, without specifying the parameters. The standard way to declare this would be

```
std::default_random_engine generator;

std::normal_distribution<double> distribution1(mu, sigma);
```

However, I'm not sure if this works in the .h file, because this actually instantiates the class.  I'm thinking maybe I should declare a pointer to a normal distribution object, or something of that nature, but I am not sure of the proper syntax for this.  I would like something of the form

```
class my_rand{
   my_rand(double, double);
   std::default_random_engine generator;
   std::normal_distribution<double> distribution;
   double return_rand();
}

my_rand::my_rand(double mu, double sigma){
   distribution.param(mu,sigma);
}

double my_rand::return_rand(){
   return distribution(generator);
}
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the *Singleton Pattern*.  And initializing it on every call is probably a bad idea, esp. if you initialize it w/ the same seed each time.

Comment: It may be *Singleton* or just normal member, depending on use case. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think it would be advisable to generate a different seed each time so that you are not getting the same distribution on each call. The trade off here is not so much being slower but it would cause for a little more code bloat so to speak; but you could inline your function call for the initialization process. This will speed things up but it will also make your executable bigger. However; with the standard template libraries random generators there are a few ways to do this to guarantee a different seed each time.

Comment: I'm not sure if the singleton pattern is what I'm looking for.  I would like help with the specific syntax for this problem if possible.

Comment: a) Just make the generator `static` or `thread_local` in whatever function that uses it, the distribution can stay as is. b) Don't use `std::default_random_engine`, it's a shitty choice on some platforms (maybe even most). Use `mt19937` instead.

Comment: Great, thanks.  So in other words I would use                                           static std::mt19937 generator;
static std::normal_distribution<double> distribution1(mu, sigma); ?

Comment: Actually, I still don't know how to do this.  If someone could modify the code I wrote in the question to make it work that would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A few years back I wrote a couple of classes to encapsulate the standard's random generators & distributions classes. Here is what my classes look like:
There are a few ways to seed the generators and different generators to use; and the classes `RandomEngine` & `RandomDistribution`  work seamlessly together as they are simply static methods in wrapper classes. There are also `typedefs` after the classes to ease the amount of typing: `RE` & `RD` respectively.

**RandomGenerator.h**

```
#ifndef RANDOM_GENERATOR_H
#define RANDOM_GENERATOR_H

#include <limits>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

class RandomEngine {
public:
    using Clock = std::conditional_t<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady,
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
        std::chrono::steady_clock>;

    // Used To Determine Which Seeding Process To Use
    enum SeedType {
        USE_CHRONO_CLOCK,
        USE_RANDOM_DEVICE,
        USE_SEED_VALUE, 
        USE_SEED_SEQ,
    }; // SeedType

    // This Enum Is Not In Use - It Is A Visual Reference Only; But If User Wants To
    // Use It For Their Own Pupose They Are Free To Do So.
    enum EngineType {
        // Default Random Engine
        DEFAULT_RANDOM_ENGINE,

        // Linear Congruential Engines
        MINSTD_RAND0,
        MINSTD_RAND,

        // Mersenne Twister Engines 
        MT19937,
        MT19937_64,

        // Subtract With Carry Engines 
        RANLUX24_BASE,
        RANLUX48_BASE,

        // Discard Block Engines 
        RANLUX24,
        RANLUX48,

        // Shuffle Order Engines
        KNUTH_B,

    }; // EngineType

protected:
    RandomEngine(){}

    // Internal Helper Function  
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getRandomDevice()
    static std::random_device& getRandomDevice() {
        static std::random_device device{};
        return device;
    } // getRandomDevice

public:
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getTimeNow()
    static unsigned int getTimeNow() {
        unsigned int now = static_cast<unsigned int>(Clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
        return now;
    } // getTimeNow

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getDefaultRandomEngine()
    static std::default_random_engine& getDefaultRandomEngine( SeedType type, unsigned seedValue = 0, std::seed_seq& seq = std::seed_seq{} ) {
        static std::default_random_engine engine{};

        switch ( type ) {
            case USE_CHRONO_CLOCK: {
                engine.seed( getTimeNow() );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_VALUE: {
                engine.seed( seedValue );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_SEQ: {
                engine.seed( seq );
                break;
            }
            default: {
                engine.seed( getRandomDevice()() );
                break;
            }
        }

        return engine;
    } // getDefaultRandomEngine

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getMinStd_Rand0()
    static std::minstd_rand0& getMinStd_Rand0( SeedType type, unsigned seedValue = 0, std::seed_seq& seq = std::seed_seq{} ) {
        static std::minstd_rand0 engine{};

        switch ( type ) {
            case USE_CHRONO_CLOCK: {
                engine.seed( getTimeNow() );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_VALUE: {
                engine.seed( seedValue );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_SEQ: {
                engine.seed( seq );
                break;
            }
            default: {
                engine.seed( getRandomDevice()() );
                break;
            }
        }

        return engine;
    } // getMinStd_Rand0

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getMinStd_Rand()
    static std::minstd_rand& getMinStd_Rand( SeedType type, unsigned seedValue = 0, std::seed_seq& seq = std::seed_seq{} ) {
        static std::minstd_rand engine{};

        switch( type ) {
            case USE_CHRONO_CLOCK: {
                engine.seed( getTimeNow() );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_VALUE: {
                engine.seed( seedValue );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_SEQ: {
                engine.seed(seq);
                break;
            }
            default: {
                engine.seed( getRandomDevice()() );
                break;
            }
        }

        return engine;
    } // getMinStd_Rand

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getMt19937()
    static std::mt19937& getMt19937( SeedType type, unsigned seedValue = 0, std::seed_seq& seq = std::seed_seq{} ) {
        static std::mt19937 engine{};

        switch ( type ) {
            case USE_CHRONO_CLOCK: {
                engine.seed( getTimeNow() );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_VALUE: {
                engine.seed( seedValue );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_SEQ: {
                engine.seed( seq );
                break;
            }
            default: {
                engine.seed( getRandomDevice()() );
                break;
            }
        }

        return engine;
    } //getMt19937

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getMt19937_64()
    static std::mt19937_64& getMt19937_64( SeedType type, unsigned seedValue = 0, std::seed_seq& seq = std::seed_seq{} ) {
        static std::mt19937_64 engine{};

        switch ( type ) {
            case USE_CHRONO_CLOCK: {
                engine.seed( getTimeNow() );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_VALUE: {
                engine.seed( seedValue );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_SEQ: {
                engine.seed( seq );
                break;
            }
            default: {
                engine.seed( getRandomDevice()() );
                break;
            }
        }

        return engine;
    } // getMt19937_64

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getRanLux24_base()
    static std::ranlux24_base& getRanLux24_base( SeedType type, unsigned seedValue = 0, std::seed_seq& seq = std::seed_seq{} ) {
        static std::ranlux24_base engine{};

        switch ( type ) {
            case USE_CHRONO_CLOCK: {
                engine.seed( getTimeNow() );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_VALUE: {
                engine.seed( seedValue );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_SEQ: {
                engine.seed( seq );
                break;
            }
            default: {
                engine.seed( getRandomDevice()() );
                break;
            }
        }

        return engine;
    } // getRanLux24_base

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getRanLux48_base()
    static std::ranlux48_base& getRanLux48_base( SeedType type, unsigned seedValue = 0, std::seed_seq& seq = std::seed_seq{} ) {
        static std::ranlux48_base engine{};

        switch ( type ) {
            case USE_CHRONO_CLOCK: {
                engine.seed( getTimeNow() );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_VALUE: {
                engine.seed( seedValue );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_SEQ: {
                engine.seed( seq );
                break;
            }
            default: {
                engine.seed( getRandomDevice()() );
                break;
            }
        }

        return engine;
    } // getRanLux48_base

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getRanLux24()
    static std::ranlux24& getRanLux24( SeedType type, unsigned seedValue = 0, std::seed_seq& seq = std::seed_seq{} ) {
        static std::ranlux24 engine{};

        switch ( type ) {
            case USE_CHRONO_CLOCK: {
                engine.seed( getTimeNow() );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_VALUE: {
                engine.seed( seedValue );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_SEQ: {
                engine.seed( seq );
                break;
            }
            default: {
                engine.seed( getRandomDevice()() );
                break;
            }
        }

        return engine;
    } // getRanLux24

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getRanLux48()
    static std::ranlux48& getRanLux48( SeedType type, unsigned seedValue = 0, std::seed_seq& seq = std::seed_seq{} ) {
        static std::ranlux48 engine{};

        switch ( type ) {
            case USE_CHRONO_CLOCK: {
                engine.seed( getTimeNow() );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_VALUE: {
                engine.seed( seedValue );
                break;
            }
            case USE_SEED_SEQ: {
                engine.seed( seq );
                break;
            }
            default: {
                engine.seed( getRandomDevice()() );
                break;
            }
        }

        return engine;
    } //getRanLux48

}; // RandomEngine

class RandomDistribution {
public:
    // This Enum Is Not In Use - It Is A Visual Reference Only; But If User Wants To
    // Use It For Their Own Pupose They Are Free To Do So.
    enum DistributionType {
        // Uniform Distributions
        UNIFORM_INT,
        UNIFORM_INT_DISTRIBUTION,
        UNIFORM_REAL,
        UNIFORM_REAL_DISTRIBUTION,
        // GENERATE_CANONICAL, - This is a function template and not a class template use it directly form std:: <random> c++11

        // Bernoulli Distributions
        BERNOULLI_DISTRIBUTION,
        BINOMAIL_DISTRIBUTION,
        NEGATIVE_BINOMIAL_DISTRIBUTION,
        GEOMETRIC_DISTRIBUTION,

        // Poisson Distributions
        POISSON_DISTRIBUTION,
        EXPONENTIAL_DISTRIBUTION,
        GAMMA_DISTRIBUTION,
        WEIBULL_DISTRIBUTION,
        EXTREME_VALUE_DISTRIBUTION,

        // Normal Distributions
        NORMAL_DISTRIBUTION,
        LOGNORMAL_DISTRIBUTION,
        CHI_SQUARED_DISTRIBUTION,
        CAUCHY_DISTRIBUTION,
        FISHER_F_DISTRIBUTION,
        STUDENT_T_DISTRIBUTION,

        // Sampling Distributions
        DISCRETE_DISTRIBUTION,
        PIECEWISE_CONSTANT_DISTRIBUTION,
        PIECEWISE_LINEAR_DISTRIBUTION
    }; // DistributionType

protected:
    RandomDistribution(){}

public:

    // UNIFORM DISTRIBUTIONS

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getUniformIntDistribution()
    template<class IntType = int>
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<IntType>& getUniformIntDistribution( IntType lowerBound = 0, IntType upperBound = (std::numeric_limits<IntType>::max)() ) {
        static std::uniform_int_distribution<IntType> dist( lowerBound, upperBound );
        return dist;
    } // getUniformIntDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getUniformRealDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double>
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<RealType>& getUniformRealDistribution( RealType lowerBound = 0.0, RealType upperBound = 1.0 ) {
        static std::uniform_real_distribution<RealType> dist( lowerBound, upperBound );
        return dist;
    } // getUniformRealDistribution



    // BERNOULLI DISTRIBUTIONS

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getBernoulliDistribution()
    static std::bernoulli_distribution& getBernoulliDistribution( double probability = 0.5 ) {
        static std::bernoulli_distribution dist( probability );
        return dist;
    } // getBernoulliDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getBinomialDistribution()
    template<class IntType = int>
    static std::binomial_distribution<IntType>& getBinomialDistribution( IntType numTrials = 1, double probability = 0.5 ) {
        static std::binomial_distribution<IntType> dist( numTrials, probability );
        return dist;
    } // getBinomialDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getNegativeBinomialDistribution()
    template<class IntType = int>
    static std::negative_binomial_distribution<IntType>& getNegativeBinomialDistribution( IntType numTrialFailures = 1, double probability = 0.5 ) {
        static std::negative_binomial_distribution<IntType> dist( numTrialFailures, probability );
        return dist;
    } // getNegativeBinomialDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getGeometricDistribution()
    template<class IntType = int>
    static std::geometric_distribution<IntType>& getGeometricDistribution( double probability = 0.5 ) {
        static std::geometric_distribution<IntType> dist( probability ); 
        return dist;
    } // getGeometricDistribution



    // POISSON DISTRIBUTIONS

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getPoissonDistribution()
    template<class IntType = int>
    static std::poisson_distribution<IntType>& getPoissonDistribution( double mean = 1.0 ) {
        static std::poisson_distribution<IntType> dist( mean );
        return dist;
    } // getPoissonDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getExponentialDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double>
    static std::exponential_distribution<RealType>& getExponentialDistribution( RealType rate = 1.0 ) {
        static std::exponential_distribution<RealType> dist( rate );
        return dist;
    } // getExponentialDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getGammDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double>
    static std::gamma_distribution<RealType>& getGammaDistribution( RealType alpha_shape = 1.0, RealType beta_scale = 1.0 ) {
        static std::gamma_distribution<RealType> dist( alpha_shape, beta_scale );
        return dist;
    } // getGammaDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getWeibullDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double>
    static std::weibull_distribution<RealType>& getWeibullDistribution( RealType alpha_shape = 1.0, RealType beta_scale = 1.0 ) {
        static std::weibull_distribution<RealType> dist( alpha_shape, beta_scale );
        return dist;
    } // getWeibullDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getExtremeValueDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double>
    static std::extreme_value_distribution<RealType>& getExtremeValueDistribution( RealType location = 0.0, RealType scale = 1.0 ) {
        static std::extreme_value_distribution<RealType> dist( location, scale );
        return dist;
    } // getExtremeValueDistribution


    // NORMAL DISTRIBUTIONS

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getNormalDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double>
    static std::normal_distribution<RealType>& getNormalDistribution( RealType mean = 0.0, RealType stddev = 1.0 ) {
        static std::normal_distribution<RealType> dist( mean, stddev );
        return dist;
    } // getNormaDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getLogNormalDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double>
    static std::lognormal_distribution<RealType>& getLogNormalDistribution( RealType logScale = 0.0, RealType shape = 1.0 ) {
        static std::lognormal_distribution<RealType> dist( logScale, shape );
        return dist;
    } // getLogNormalDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getChiSquaredDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double>
    static std::chi_squared_distribution<RealType>& getChiSquaredDistribution( RealType degreesOfFreedom = 1.0 ) {
        static std::chi_squared_distribution<RealType> dist( degreesOfFreedom );
        return dist;
    } // getChiSquaredDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getCauchyDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double>
    static std::cauchy_distribution<RealType>& getCauchyDistribution( RealType location = 0.0, RealType scale = 1.0 ) {
        static std::cauchy_distribution<RealType> dist( location, scale );
        return dist;
    } // getCauchyDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getFisherFDistribution() Both m,n are degress of freedom
    template<class RealType = double>
    static std::fisher_f_distribution<RealType>& getFisherFDistribution( RealType m = 1.0, RealType n = 1.0 ) {
        static std::fisher_f_distribution<RealType> dist( m, n );
        return dist;
    } // getFisherFDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getStudentTDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double>
    static std::student_t_distribution<RealType>& getStudentTDistribution( RealType degreesOfFreedom = 1.0 ) {
        static std::student_t_distribution<RealType> dist( degreesOfFreedom );
        return dist;
    } // getStudentTDistribution


    // SAMPLING DISTRIBUTIONS

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  getDiscreteDistribution()
    template<class IntType = int>
    static std::discrete_distribution<IntType>& getDiscreteDistribution() {
        static std::discrete_distribution<IntType> dist;
        return dist;
    } // getDiscreteDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  getDiscreteDistribution()
    template<class IntType = int, class InputIt>
    static std::discrete_distribution<IntType>& getDiscreteDistribution( InputIt first, InputIt last ) {
        static std::discrete_distribution<IntType> dist( first, last );
        return dist;
    } // getDiscreteDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  getDiscreteDistribution()
    template<class IntType = int>
    static std::discrete_distribution<IntType>& getDiscreteDistribution( std::initializer_list<double> weights ) {
        static std::discrete_distribution<IntType> dist( weights );
        return dist;
    } // getDiscreteDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  getDiscreteDistribution()
    template<class IntType = int, class UnaryOperation>
    static std::discrete_distribution<IntType>& getDiscreteDistribution( std::size_t count, double xmin, double xmax, UnaryOperation unary_op ) {
        static std::discrete_distribution<IntType> dist( count, xmin, xmax, unary_op );
        return dist;
    } // getDiscreteDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getPiecewiseConstantDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double>
    static std::piecewise_constant_distribution<RealType>& getPiecewiseConstantDistribution() {
        static std::piecewise_constant_distribution<RealType> dist;
        return dist;
    } // getPiecewiseConstantDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getPiecewiseConstantDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double, class InputIt1, class InputIt2>
    static std::piecewise_constant_distribution<RealType>& getPiecewiseConstantDistribution( InputIt1 first_i, InputIt1 last_i, InputIt2 first_w ) {
        static std::piecewise_constant_distribution<RealType> dist( first_i, last_i, first_w );
        return dist;
    } // getPiecewiseConstantDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getPiecewiseConstantDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double, class UnaryOperation>
    static std::piecewise_constant_distribution<RealType>& getPiecewiseConstantDistribution( std::initializer_list<RealType> bl, UnaryOperation fw ) {
        static std::piecewise_constant_distribution<RealType> dist( bl, fw );
        return dist;
    } // getPiecewiseConstantDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getPiecewiseConstantDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double, class UnaryOperation>
    static std::piecewise_constant_distribution<RealType>& getPiecewiseConstantDistribution( std::size_t nw, RealType xmin, RealType xmax, UnaryOperation fw ) {
        static std::piecewise_constant_distribution<RealType> dist( nw, xmin, xmax, fw );
        return dist;
    } // getPiecewiseConstantDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getPiecewiseLinearDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double>
    static std::piecewise_linear_distribution<RealType>& getPiecewiseLinearDistribution() {
        static std::piecewise_linear_distribution<RealType> dist;
        return dist;
    } // getPiecewiseLinearDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getPiecewiseLinearDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double, class InputIt1, class InputIt2>
    static std::piecewise_linear_distribution<RealType>& getPiecewiseLinearDistribution( InputIt1 first_i, InputIt1 last_i, InputIt2 first_w ) {
        static std::piecewise_linear_distribution<RealType> dist( first_i, last_i, first_w );
        return dist;
    } // getPiecewiseLinearDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getPiecewiseLinearDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double, class UnaryOperation>
    static std::piecewise_linear_distribution<RealType>& getPiecewiseLinearDistribution( std::initializer_list<RealType> bl, UnaryOperation fw ) {
        static std::piecewise_linear_distribution<RealType> dist( bl, fw );
        return dist;
    } // getPiecewiseLinearDistribution

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // getPiecewiseLinearDistribution()
    template<class RealType = double, class UnaryOperation>
    static std::piecewise_linear_distribution<RealType>& getPiecewiseLinearDistribution( std::size_t nw, RealType xmin, RealType xmax, UnaryOperation fw ) {
        static std::piecewise_linear_distribution<RealType> dist( nw, xmin, xmax, fw );
        return dist;
    } // getPiecewiseLinearDistribution

}; // RandomDistribution

typedef RandomEngine RE;
typedef RandomDistribution RD;

#endif // RANDOM_GENERATOR_H
```

Here is a single use of my classes above. There are multiple options in how to use them as well.

**main.cpp**

```
// #include "Logger.h"
#include "RandomGenerator.h"
#include <isotream>
#include <sstream>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// main()
int main() {    
    // Logger log( "log.txt" );

    std::ostringstream strStream;
    strStream << "Random number generated Between [1,9] using default random engine & uniform int distribution is: " << std::endl;
    //Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
    std::cout << strStream.str();

    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> uid = RD::getUniformIntDistribution<unsigned>(1, 9);
    // std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> uid( 1, 9 );
    for ( unsigned int i = 1; i < 101; i++ ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        unsigned val = uid( RE::getDefaultRandomEngine( RE::SeedType::USE_CHRONO_CLOCK, 14 ) );

        strStream << i << " : " << val << std::endl;
        //Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
        std::cout << strStream.str();
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    for ( unsigned int i = 1; i < 101; i++ ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        // Using the same distribution above but reseeding it with a different type of seeding method.
        unsigned val = uid( RE::getDefaultRandomEngine( RE::SeedType::USE_RANDOM_DEVICE ) );

        strStream << i << " : " << val << std::endl;
        // Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_CONSOLE );
        std::cout << strStream.str();
    }

    return 0;
} // main
```

I commented out the lines of code that pertains to my logger class and replaced it with a simple `std::cout` call. The way that this is currently designed is that you only need to create a local or member instance of a `distribution type` as there is no need to create a local instance of an actual `Random Engine` or `Seeding` object as this all works in static storage. I hope this helps you as it is fairly efficient.

**EDIT** -- Here is another sample using Mersenne Twister with a real distribution between [0,1] with 50 samples seeding it with chrono clock:

```
int main() {

    std::ostringstream strStream;
    strStream << "Random number generated between [0.0, 1.0] \nusing mersenne & chrono clock for seeding:\n";
    std::cout << strStream.str();

    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> urd = RD::getUniformRealDistribution<double>( 0.0, 1.0 );
    for ( unsigned i = 1; i <= 50; i++ ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        double val = urd( RE::getMt19937( RE::SeedType::USE_CHRONO_CLOCK, 12 ) );
        strStream << i << " : " << val << "\n";
        std::cout << strStream.str();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your solution, sorry.  Do you think it is better than what I wrote in my answer?

Comment: @TeddyBaker In no way am I trying to say that it is better; I only offered a small part of a library that I had written about a year ago. I encapsulated nearly all of the standard library's random engine, seeding mechanisms & distributions into 2 classes that do not instantiate an actual object. Since the constructors are protected you can not declare an instance of these types. All methods are static as these classes act as a wrapper. If you look at the `RE` class you will see that each `engine` can take any of the methods of seeding and does it for you on the fly. ...

Comment: @TeddyBaker ... Looking at the `RD` class you can see that this wrapper class contains all distribution types as static template functions that takes all the necessary parameters for their range(s) and it returns back the processed distribution. Normally when using the standard directly you will create an instance of a random engine and an instance of a distribution type with its range of values, then seed the engine to generate the distribution. Here there is no need to have an object of the engine as it is done in static storage - static scope. It is the distribution that you create locally.

Comment: @TeddyBaker When you do create an instance of the distribution type you want to use you do have to create an instance of it from the `std::` library itself but you can set that equal to the `RD::static_method( params... )`.  Then after you have the distribution that you want locally or even on the heap or in some other class you then use the declared & initialized variable of the distribution type passing to its overloaded copy constructor the random engine type & its seeding mechanism and assign that to a local variable of the template type as seen within the main function above.

Comment: @Teddy I edited the answer with another sample at the end using mersenne twister across a real distribution between the range of [0,1] with 50 samples seeding the engine using chrono clock for seeding with a factor of 12.

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured it out, this compiles and seems to work

```
class my_rand{
    public:
    my_rand(double, double);
    std::mt19937 * generator;
    std::normal_distribution<double>* distribution;
    double return_rand();
};

my_rand::my_rand(double mu, double sigma){
   distribution=new std::normal_distribution<double>;
   std::normal_distribution<double> dtemp(5.0,2.0);
   distribution->param(dtemp.param());
   generator=new std::mt19937;
}

double my_rand::return_rand(){
   return (*distribution)(*generator);
}
```